# Why doesn't my checkbox work?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a checkbox inside gridview. I want to update a `BIT` field inside database table (`true/false`) with checking/unchecking checkbox but it doesn't work.

I am filling gridview with this

```
Select  CaseHearings.pk_CaseHearings_ID, IsConveyed                  
        From CaseHearings
```

and this

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Conveyed ?">
        <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:CheckBox ID="chkBoxIsConveyed" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"
              Checked='<%# Eval("IsConveyed") == DBNull.Value? false: Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("IsConveyed")) %>' />
         </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Maybe you want the `CheckChanged` event..

Answer (score 0):

You need templates for when the gridview is in edit mode:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="MyBool" SortExpression="MyBool">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("MyBool") %>' />
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("MyBool") %>' Enabled="false" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: but my gridview is not in edit mode, would it turn to EDIT mode automatically ?

Comment: As an experiment, try using a DataSource: In setup click the advanced button to generate Insert/update/delete statements.  Then you can hook it up to a GridView and see how the wizard generates code that makes a GridView work the way a GridView was designed to work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
<Columns>
    <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true"/>
    <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="IsConveyed" HeaderText="Conveyed ?" />
    .
    .
</Columns>
```

And then implement the events `OnRowEditing` `OnRowUpdating` et cetera, to handle the edited data. Or use a `asp:SqlDataSource` or the likes depending on how you collect and bind to your data.